# My home directory is the same as "/var/www/" Apache Linux

Tags: linux, apache, directory, home-directory

I am running a small webserver off of my RaspberryPi, and I have Apache2 installed on it. Everything works fine, and I can load html, php, and javascript from other computers, etc. However, the problem I am having with is that when I installed Apache, it made my home directory, the same as "/var/www/" where all the web pages are supposed to be stored. How can I change this, because I'm pretty sure the home directory should be separate from my server.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ pwd
/var/www
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cd /var/www
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ls
cookies.png  Desktop  hello.php  index.html  test.cpp  test.html  testImage
pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

EDIT: I'm running the default Raspbien OS.

Comment: you mean like `usermod -d /path/to/new/homedir/ pi` ?

Comment: `pwd` just means "Print the name of the current/working directory". IE what folder am I in. If you were already in `/var/www`, it would just say `/var/www`. Try to go to `cd ~` and run pwd to see what your home directory is.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn it seems like he already is in `~`

Comment: @Roman however, even after `cd /var/www` it still shows `~` in the prompt.

Comment: @Jonathan... oh didn't notice that

Comment: I guess if `/var/www` was his home it would just show `~`. So I might be wrong, but he never went to another directory to show the difference. It might just be set to show `~` with the prompt regardless of directory.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/www/` is the default installation directory for Apache2.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/serverguide.pdf

Assuming you have Ubuntu installed, read over the documentation

You will stumble accross the following text:

> 1.2.1. Basic Settings This section explains Apache2 server essential configuration parameters. Refer to the Apache2 Documentation 3 for
>   more details. • Apache2 ships with a virtual-host-friendly default
>   configuration. That is, it is configured with a single default virtual
>   host (using the VirtualHost directive) which can modified or used
>   as-is if you have a single site, or used as a template for additional
>   virtual hosts if you have multiple sites. If left alone, the default
>   virtual host will serve as your default site, or the site users will
>   see if the URL they enter does not match the ServerName directive of
>   any of your custom sites. To modify the default virtual host, edit the
>   file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default .

Perform

`texteditor /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

replace *texteditor*  with your preferred editor. `nano`, `vi` etc..

Remember to make a backup prior to making changes.

After making changes you are happy with run:

`service apache2 restart`

to finalize the changes to your configuration file.

**Edit:**

Run the following:

`usermod -d /path/to/new/homedir/ username`

whilst logged in as a member of the super user group.

Comment: the home directory of the user account was changed, not the document root.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit your user line in **/etc/passwd** with new path for your home dir.
Or run **usermod** as mentioned above.